# Why does my Spring @EventListener show different transactional behavior on event submission than when being called directly?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

When using the `@EventListener` functionality with Spring Data's repositories the behavior is different than when calling the same code procedural.

My persistent objects publish events using the following base class:

```
  public abstract class Aggregate  {

      @Transient
      private transient final Set<Object> events = new LinkedHashSet<>();

      protected <T> T registerEvent(T event) {
          this.events.add(event);
          return event;
      }

      @DomainEvents
      Collection<Object> events() {
          return Collections.unmodifiableSet(events);
      }

      @AfterDomainEventPublication
      void clearEvents() {
          this.events.clear();
      }
  }
```

My event listening class is implemented as follows:

```
  class Service {

      @EventListener
      public void listener(SomeEvent event) {
          someOtherRepository.save(someOtherPersistentObject);
          someOtherCode();
      }
  }
```

When the listener is triggered and `someOtherRepository`'s `save(…)` method fails a rollback will be issued. But `someOtherCode()` is executed regardless of the rollback.

But when I remove all `@EventListening` functionality and call the `listener(…)` method directly after the point where the originating repository is responsible for firing the event. Then I get a different behavior. Then `someOtherCode()` is never executed and the `someOtherRepository.save(…)` method fails immediately.

The original service responsible for publishing the event looks like this

```
public OriginatingService {
    @Transactional
    public void someMethod() {
        originatingRepoDifferentFromSomeOtherRepo.save(something);
```

Why is this happening and is there a way to force the same behavior onto my event listening implementation?

Comment: Can you please clarify what "someOtherRepository's save method fails and a rollback will be issued someOtherCode(); is executed regardless of the rollback." means? A rollback is bound to an `@Transactional` method. If the original event is not thrown from one, `save(…)` will be the only transactional method and thus it will not conclude. `someOtherCode()` is only executed if there's not exception and `save (…)` should always fail with one, if it fails at all.

Comment: By that sentence I mean that when someOtherRepository.save() is will execute a failing insert (for example due to a duplicate key) then it does not fail directly rather it fails after completing the whole listener method code. Hence someOtherCode(); is executed. We have tried adding the @Transactional annotation the the listener method but that doesn't make a difference. 

While if we do the same thing procedurally from one service method as test, when someOtherRepository.save is called it immediatly fails and someOtherCode(); will never get executed. Which is what we are aiming for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because writes to the database may be delayed until transaction commit i.e. when the transactional method returns.

Update as below to explicitly trigger an immediate flush:

```
 @EventListener
  public void listener(SomeEvent event) {
      someOtherRepository.saveAndFlush(someOtherPersistentObject);
      someOtherCode();
  }
```